# How do i use the queue properly in this

Tags: python, queue

Found this question [here](https://pastebin.com/Acf0C4QY)

I have come up with an approach but it seems the queing isn't happening at all. The 1st testcase passes but the 2nd one fails which specifically tests the queueing. Any help would be appreciated.

```
def solution(times):
    res = []
    queue = []
    currEnd = 0

    for time in times:
        if not queue:
            currEnd = max(time, currEnd)+300
            res.append(currEnd)
        else:
            # while queue and queue[0] <= currEnd:
            while queue and max(queue[0], currEnd)+300 <= time:
                currEnd = max(queue.pop(0), currEnd)+300
                res.append(currEnd)
            if not queue:
                currEnd = max(time, currEnd)+300
                res.append(currEnd)
            else:
                if len(queue) <= 10:
                    queue.append(time)
                else:
                    res.append(time)

    while queue:
        currEnd = max(queue.pop(0), currEnd)+300
        res.append(currEnd)

    return res
```